# Electricity generator

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits, electrons

We know in an electricity generator , electrons move from negative voltage to positive voltage of the stator winding and we can use that electric  power on its way , so is it possible for the stator to loss all of its electrons((because we consumed it )) so it can not produce more voltage and  electric  current in the generator?i mean does it finally turn   to positive ions ?

Comment: A complete circuit returns the electrons.

Answer (score 1):

An electricity generator does not create electrons nor do appliances consume them. The electricity generator creates an electromotive force (emf) by moving the generator rotor's conductors in a magnetic field provided by the stator. This emf drives electrons. The resulting electron motion is called current. Without sufficient emf, the electrons are not able to power anything, but they do not 'disappear'.

When something is being powered, the electrons are always moving around a circuit, or between earth (or ground) and some circuit. If electrons are moving from earth to the circuit at one point, somewhere else, electrons are moving from the electrical circuit to earth, unless you are discharging static electricity or a battery, which is a transitory situation. The electrons are not consumed in the average electrical circuit.

Answer (score 0):

the condition you describe is analogous to the state in which the generator is spinning but the load resistance to which it is connected is extremely large, so the current being pushed by the generator through the load goes to zero. In this case, the generator still applies its full rated voltage to the load, but this is not going to be sufficient to ionize the metal wire in its windings.

Comment: i know that it is not possible for a moment , but what happens  after a long time for the generator working in that condition ? i think finally it may ionize. is that true ?

Comment: nope. the generator sustains its output voltage, charge piles up but with nowhere to go, it then opposes any further pileup. it will never ionize, not even if the voltage is tens of thousands of volts. In fact, for extremely high voltages, the air surrounding the wires breaks down and ionizes before the wire can.

Comment: give me the reference of your answer

Comment: any electrical engineering undergraduate textbook that deals with power generation and transmission will describe the physics involved.

Comment: you sad that charge piles up but with nowhere to go , but i described a condition where charge is completely consumed , not pileup.

Comment: Then it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: you mean if we are going to consuming  all of the  charge produced by a generator , it is going to pileup the electrons ?

Comment: Yes; if you put a capacitor across the terminals of a generator, it will charge up the the output voltage of the generator and then stay there.